# AWS EKS - Wildcard in kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am trying to understand if I can specify a wildcard domain in the kubernetes ingress configuration.
I am running AWS Eks cluster.
I have a web pages, where url is structured as client.example.com but for the invite and login app I need to redirect traffic to related invite/login services. All other traffic should normally go to the main-service.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: -ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip


spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: main-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: login.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: login-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: invite.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: invite-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Is it possible to create such a configuration within Kubernetes ingress?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some investigation, wildcard is supported in versions >=1.18. Rules are evaluated in the specified order.

So if you have something like:

```
*.example.com
invite.example.com
loginm.example.com
```

then your order should be

```
invite.example.com
login.example.com
```

and the last one is

```
*.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard hostname is officially  supported starting in 1.18:

"Many Ingress providers have supported wildcard hostname matching like *.foo.com matching app1.foo.com, but until now the spec assumed an exact FQDN match of the host. Hosts can now be precise matches (for example “foo.bar.com”) or a wildcard (for example “*.foo.com”). Precise matches require that the http host header matches the Host setting. Wildcard matches require the http host header is equal to the suffix of the wildcard rule."

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/#support-for-hostname-wildcards

Comment: Thanks, I have tried and looks like not working for me. Is there any order of rules evaluation?

Comment: Check your cluster is >= 1.18 and that your ingress controller supports wildcard hostname.